# Sink too low for p pipe

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, drain, sink

[image]

My new sink is too deep for the drain. How can I plumb it to lower the p pipe?

Comment: What's that barbed fitting on the side of the tailpiece for?

Comment: For the dishwasher drain

Comment: The drain piece appears to be deeper than standard. Could you get a drain piece which projects down less? https://www.amazon.com/Perfetto-Kitchen-Bath-Stainless-Replacement/dp/B01NA9ODD1/ref=sr_1_11?ie=UTF8&qid=1524901337&sr=8-11&keywords=sink+drain+parts But I like the use of the nipple proposed by @ThreePhaseEel.

Answer (score 3):

### Throw a nipple in there, just don't make it too long

What I'd do to fix this, considering you can't chop the tailpiece down without removing the dishwasher inlet, would be to insert a DWV-PVC pipe nipple of some sort between the outlet bend and the P-trap itself.  This should be fine as long as you don't exceed the 24" distance limit prescribed in IPC 1002.1 (inapplicable exceptions omitted, erratum applied):

> Each plumbing fixture shall be separately trapped by a liquid-seal trap, except as otherwise permitted by this code.  The vertical distance from the fixture outlet to the trap weir shall not exceed 24 inches (610 mm), and the horizontal distance shall not exceed 30 inches (762mm) measured from the centerline of the fixture outlet to the centerline of the inlet of the trap.  The height of a clothes washer standpipe above a trap shall conform to Section 802.3.3.  A fixture shall not be double trapped.

Answer (score 1):

Change sink strainer for short regular one that gives you enough space for that